docker-compose set environment variable as output of host command
Is it possible to set an environment variable in docker-compose.yaml as the output of a command? I thought this was working, however as I'm looking over things in my service and when it's running I'm getting VERSION=$(git describe) where what I'm looking to see is something likeVERSION=v1.0.0
For example:
name: myservice
services:
  agent:
    image: ubuntu
    user: root
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VERSION=$(git describe)



There is no support for setting a variable to the output of a command. That would allow a compose file to execute arbitrary shell commands, which is undesirable for a number of reasons. You can always do something like VERSION=$(git describe) docker compose up, as long you set VERSION: ${VERSION} in your environment section.`

@larsks is correct
Obviously this 'could' be undesired however I'm not confident that this is an absolute truth
It's not supported. I wish the docs clearly mentioned this. Especially when you can do it with env vars

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but how about this?
 docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  agent:
    container_name: ubuntu-agent
    build:
        context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    # Command for testing.
    command: ["./test.sh"]

This assumes that the current directory is a Git repository and mounts it on /app in a container.
 Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install -y \
        git

WORKDIR /app

# Get around ownership issues.
RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /app

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["bash"]

The git config command ensures that Git doesn't complain about inconsistent ownership of the Git repository.
 entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

export VERSION=$(git describe)

exec "$@"

The entrypoint script exports the required environment variable. Again, this will only work if the current working directory is a Git repository!
 test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "The version is: $VERSION."

The test.sh script is just there to establish that the environment variable is indeed set for processes running on the container. You would replace this with whatever you are actually wanting to run in the container.
This solution feels rather elaborate, but in the absence of more information about what you are trying to do it appears to satisfy the requirement of creating an environment variable set to the output from git describe.

Thats very dangerous and should be only used for local environments. Reasons: Never put the full git history into a docker-container and putting the whole app as volume breaks the concept of the docker layers.
